# how to calculate the total price of your cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, cart, shopping-cart

I was creating a shopping cart using react and redux and everything works perfectly without any errors I'm wondering how do I calculate the total price by adding up all the items in the cart

my cart-slice file

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState: {
    items: [],
    totalQuantity: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    addItemToCart(state, action) {
      const newItem = action.payload;
      const existingItem = state.items.find((item) => item.id === newItem.id);
      state.totalQuantity++;
      if (!existingItem) {
        state.items.push({
          id: newItem.id,
          price: newItem.price,
          quantity: 1,
          totalPrice: newItem.price,
          name: newItem.title,
        });
      } else {
        existingItem.quantity++;
        existingItem.totalPrice = existingItem.totalPrice + newItem.price;
      }
    },
    removeItemFromCart(state, action) {
      const id = action.payload;
      const existingItem = state.items.find(item => item.id === id);
      state.totalQuantity--;
      if (existingItem.quantity === 1) {
        state.items = state.items.filter(item => item.id !== id);
      } else {
        existingItem.quantity--;
        existingItem.totalPrice = existingItem.totalPrice - existingItem.price;
      }
    },
  },
});

export const cartActions = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice;
```

the cart.js file

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import Card from '../UI/Card';
import classes from './Cart.module.css';
import CartItem from './CartItem';

const Cart = (props) => {
  const cartItems = useSelector((state) => state.cart.items);



  return (
    <Card className={classes.cart}>
      <h2>Your Shopping Cart</h2>
      <ul>
        {cartItems.map((item) => (
          <CartItem
            key={item.id}
            item={{
              id: item.id,
              title: item.name,
              quantity: item.quantity,
              total: item.totalPrice,
              price: item.price,
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

the cart item file

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import classes from './CartItem.module.css';
import { cartActions } from '../../store/cart-slice';
import { useState } from 'react';
const CartItem = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  const { title, quantity, total, price, id } = props.item;




  const removeItemHandler = (e) => {
    dispatch(cartActions.removeItemFromCart(id));
  };

  const addItemHandler = () => {
    dispatch(
      cartActions.addItemToCart({
        id,
        title,
        price,
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <> 
    <li className={classes.item}>
      <header>
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <div className={classes.price}>
          ${total.toFixed(2)}{' '}
          <span className={classes.itemprice}>(${price.toFixed(2)}/item)</span>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div className={classes.details}>
        <div className={classes.quantity}>
          x <span>{quantity}</span>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <button onClick={removeItemHandler}>-</button>
          <button onClick={addItemHandler}>+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    </>
  );
};

export default CartItem;
```

can somebody please help me on how do we calculate the total price of the cart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do it in your reducers (addItemToCart, removeItemFromCart), or add another reducer with action that does that for you in a side effect.

Watching your implementation I see that you are mutating your state which is an anti-pattern. Redux is way safer to use and easier to manage with immutable state.

So instead of

```
state.totalQuantity++;
```

it is way better to return a new state object

```
{ ...state, totalQuantity: state.totalQuantity }
```

I don't know exactly whether redux/toolkit already copies the state internally, but you should not take that as given. Always return a new state.

Now to your Question (I dont know how your Item model looks like):

```
const totalPrice = state.items
   .map(everyItem => {
       return everyItem.quantity * everyItem.price;
    })
   .reduce((totalPrice, singleItemPrice) => totalPrice + singleItemPrice, 0);
```

Key takeaway here should be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: hey thank you for the solution it works. and yes redux toolkit does store the state internally and you can mutate the original state with redux toolkit but you shouldn't be doing the same with only redux.
once again thank you for the help:)

Comment: Although this is a perfectly fine solution, keep in mind that this makes your state object and reducer more complex. It is considered good practise to [derive additional values](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#keep-state-minimal-and-derive-additional-values) from your state instead of saving them along.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a perfect use case for a [Memoized Selector](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors#writing-memoized-selectors-with-reselect). Since you have state with a `items` array in it you can create a selector to reduces this state to a single number. For example:

```
const selectCart = state => state.cart

const selectTotalPrice = createSelector([selectCart], (cart) => {
  return cart.items.reduce((total, item) => (item.price * quantity) + total, 0);
})
```